# Inserting the icon in the center of Polygon , drawing poylgon with svg

Tags: html, svg

I am drawing the poylygon using the svg styles and css . 
And wanted to insert an icon like pointer in the center of polygon.
How can that be done ?

Exp: In a world map , placeing icons on each state center.. 
Note : we are not drawing map using google map. We are drawing by svg only.

Thanks & Regards,
Murali

Comment: If you search this site, you'll find plenty of information on how to draw polygons and how to find the centre of a polygon. So what exactly is your problem? What have you tried so far? Why didn't it give you the results you expected?

Comment: Hi , i am not aware of how to get the center of polygon...And I am giving u sample code. I am not sure which elements or tags to use for placing the pointer(icon or jpeg) on svg polygon.